# Javascript get only even hours period based on new Date

Tags: javascript, date

Based on actual time (for example 01/08/2018 à 12:03:56) i need to have only even hours (next period and current) :

```
const getEvenHoursFromDate = (date) => {
 return {
   nextSlice,
   previousSlice
  } 
 }

getEvenHoursFromDate(new Date())
```

Output :

```
{
  nextSlice : '14:00:00-01/08/2018',
  previousSlice: '12:00:00-01/08/2018'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personally, i do not recommend to use not standard format for date presentation.
its better if it will be ISO format.
and inside javascript date instance is better than any text presentation

```js
function pad(num, prefix = '0'){
 return (prefix + num).slice(-2);
}

function dateFormat(date){
 return `${pad(date.getHours())}:${pad(date.getMinutes())}:${pad(date.getSeconds())}-${pad(date.getDate())}/${pad(date.getMonth())}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
}

function normalizeDate(date, step, add = 0){
 let hour = Math.floor(date.getHours() / step) * step + add;
 let result = new Date(date.valueOf());
 result.setHours(hour, 0,0,0);
 return result;
}

function getPeriods(date, format = d => d){
 return {
  next: format(normalizeDate(date, 2, 2)),
  current: format(normalizeDate(date, 2))
 }
}

//formatted
console.log(getPeriods(new Date(), dateFormat));
//as date instances
console.log(getPeriods(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```js
const hoursIsEven = date => date.getHours() % 2 !== 0 || date.getHours === 0

const getPreviousEvenHour = date => hoursIsEven(date) ?
  date : new Date(date).setHours(date.getHours() - 1)
  
const getNextEvenHour = date => hoursIsEven(date) ?
  new Date(date).setHours(date.getHours() + 2) :
  new Date(date).setHours(date.getHours() + 1)

const getEvenHoursFromDate = (date) => ({
  previousSlice: new Date(getPreviousEvenHour(date)),
  nextSlice: new Date(getNextEvenHour(date)),
})

console.dir(
  getEvenHoursFromDate(new Date(new Date().setHours(12)))
)

console.dir(
  getEvenHoursFromDate(new Date(new Date().setHours(13)))
)

console.dir(
  getEvenHoursFromDate(new Date(new Date().setHours(23)))
)

console.dir(
  getEvenHoursFromDate(new Date(new Date().setHours(1)))
)
```